# Rspec: How to mute internal exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

I want to check some internal behaviour of method `#abc` which also raises an error.

```
def abc
  String.class
  raise StandardError
end

describe '#abc' do
  it 'should call String.class' do
    String.should_receive(:class)
  end
end
```

`String.class` - is just an example of any method call of any class which I want to perform inside this method.

But I got an error:

```
Failure/Error: #abc
StandardError
```

How I can mute this exception so this spec would pass?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "mute" the exception; you can only catch it, either explicitly through a rescue clause or implicitly through an expectation. Note that this is different than substituting a test double for a called method. The exception is still getting raised by the code under test.

If you don't *care* whether an error is raised, then you can use:

```
abc rescue nil
```

to invoke the method. (Note: This will implicitly only catch `StandardError`)

If you want to  using the `should` or `expect` syntax, you need to place the code which is going to raise the error within a block, as in the following:

```
expect {abc}.to raise_error(StandardError)
```

Combining this with the setting of an expectation that `String.class` be invoked, you get:

```
describe '#abc' do
  it 'should call String.class' do
    expect(String).to receive(:class)
    expect {abc}.to raise_error(StandardError)
  end
end
```